# Can't export the whole BPMN model as XML in Flowable

Tags: xml, bpmn, flowable

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0hVt.png)I am modeling bpmn for a process. I used Collapsed subprocess in my process and Flowable prompts me to define that subprocess in a separate file. The problem is, I want XML for the whole process(including the subprocess) but when importing the bpmn model as XML, it's omitting the subprocess file. How to get XML for the whole process? Please help.

I tried defining the subprocess in the same file as original process and connected the subprocess to its definition using Message Flow Arrow. In the process reference, how do I specify the subprocess(don't know what the 'key' for the process means).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use an embedded subprocess, you need to ensure that the model id of all activities and sequence flows are unique across both processes. By default, the ID's of the models are usually re-used since they are auto-generated. For example `sequenceFlow4` might be in the main process diagram as well as the sub-process diagram. You need to change the model id's manually to fulfill the need.

It is also mentioned [as a tip in the Flowable Documentation about the Collapsed subprocess](https://documentation.flowable.com/latest/model/bpmn/reference/collapsed-subprocess).

Comment: Attached a screenshot of the problem we are facing. We have a collapsed subprocess called 'Validate the application' which is defined in another pool under it. We connected the subprocess to its definition using messageflow. We changed the model ids too. There's an error associated with messageFlow. Pls check the screenshot.

Comment: You need to model a subprocess into a separate diagram and link this as a process reference. The screenshot you shared is not executable, since you can't have two executable pools inside one BPMN diagram.